# Last process will suspend with multiprocessing.Pool (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading

I use Pool of multiprocessing module, but sometimes the last one or two process will be left, and the program will suspend, anyone meet this problem? why and how to solve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have find the reasons, there are two reasons

1. timeout problem, urllib2.urlopen without timeout args
2. exception problem, first function with try...except..., but it not handle timeout problem well, then give the wrong parameter to second function, then the second function with multiprocessing task suspend